# Zooming Image in WPF

Tags: wpf

I try make a zoom on image, I create style, here is :

```xml
<Style x:Key="ZoomImage" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and I apply this style in window:

```xml
<Grid Name="RootGrid" Margin="4,4,4,4">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Name="InfoGrid" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,4,4,4">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Name="UserPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4,4,4,4">
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    Margin="1,1,1,1"
                    Background="WhiteSmoke">

                <Image Name="UserImage"
                <!--Apply style -->
                Style="{StaticResource ZoomImage}"
                Margin="4,4,4,4">
                <Image.Source>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource imageConvertor}">
                        <Binding Path="ProfilePhoto"/>
                        <Binding Path="Status" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>

        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

But is does not make o zoom, where can be problem?

I use Guy advance:

```xml
<Trigger Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

but, image is not zooming if mouse is over.

Answer (score 0):

The image is not by default hit test visible- IsHitTestVisible="True" in the image, or an equivalent setter will do the job.

Comment: I think he meant setting `IsHitTestVisible` as property of the `Image`, not as trigger property. You may add `<Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True">` to your "ZoomImage" style

Comment: Yep thats right alpha-mouse. Apologies if that was not clear in my answer